# Gumball Machine Logic Math Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

[image: Gumball Machine Diagram]

You walk into an antique shop and find an unusual gumball machine. On the back of the gumball machine you can set and lock five dials with the following labels:

- Percentage (0% through 100%)
- Pink (0 through 10)
- Pink+Green (0 through 10 for pink and 0 through 10 for green individually)
- Green (0 through 10)

A note below the dials reads "Fill machine with any number of pink and green gumballs. 400 gumballs maximum capacity."

On the front of the gumball machine is a slot to place a penny and a dial to turn and receive your treat.

You buy the machine and 1000 gumballs (500 green, 500 pink) and take it home. After a few days of experimenting you've learned the following:

> - When the available number of pink gumballs is greater than the Percentage of the original (starting) number of pink gumballs it will release gumballs depending on the Pink+Green settings
> - When the available number of pink is less than or equal to the Percentage of the original (starting) number of pink gumballs it will stop releasing pink gumballs and release green gumballs as set by the Green dial
> - When all green gumballs are dispensed it will then release pink gumballs as designated by the Pink dial
> - If a remainder of gumballs is left it will dispense the remainder on the next turn
> - At least one gumball of either color must be released for each penny until the machine is empty. This means if P=0 then G>=1 else if G=0 then P>=1.

As an example:

- Fill the gumball machine with 140 pink and 100 green
- Set the Percentage dial to 70%
- Set the Pink+Green dial to 1-pink and 1-green
- Set the Pink dial to 1-pink
- Set the green dial to 2-green

Using the example settings the machine will release:

- 1-pink and 1-green gumball per turn until the number of pink is less than or equal to 70% of the original (starting) number of pink gumballs
- At less than or equal to 70% of the original (starting) pink gumballs it will release 2-green gumballs 0-pink gumballs until all green gumballs are gone
- When empty of green gumballs it will release 1-pink gumball per turn until the entire machine is empty

Clarification about remainders: If there is any remainder of a setting, such as 6 Pink when set to 7 Pink, it will dispense the 6 remaining Pink gumballs. Likewise if we are in the P+G phase and there is a remainder of Pink to reach the <=% it will dispense the remainder of Pink to reach the % or lower.

---

**CAN YOU ANSWER THE FOLLOWING FOUR QUESTIONS?**

1. How much money will it cost to get all the gumballs in the example?
2. How do you calculate for all possible settings?
3. If two green gumballs equal the cost of one pink gumball what are the best dial settings to make the most money?
4. If two green gumballs equal the cost of one pink gumball what are the worst dial settings make the least money?

Comment: can we have the gumballs in pink and green please :)

Comment:  I'll see what I can do for the one who answers all four questions first.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This seems to be a pure math problem, and likely off-topic. Is it from homework or an ongoing competition?

Comment: No, not a homework problem and not from a competition. Funny thing is the Math site said it might be better put under puzzles and now puzzles is telling me it should go under math. It really fits under both. It's a math and logic puzzle

Comment: Odd. So the percentage is a one-time thing. Wouldn't the problem be more interesting if the first rule applied *whenever* the ratio of pink to green is greater than the Percent setting?

Comment: The rules are based on a real world distribution system from my place of employment.

Comment: I'm also not clear on question 3. It looks as if you accept settings of 0. Wouldn't any setting that limits the user to one ball per cent be the same no matter what the relative costs of the balls are? Also, you can set the machine to give 0 balls and theoretically get infinite profit unless I am missing something.

Comment: The rules are somewhat unclear. In your example, the percentage of pink is $140/240*100\% = 58.33\%$. Does this mean it skips the first pink+green stage entirely?

What happens if the pink+green stage causes the pink percentage to increase until there are no greens left? Will it then skip the green-only stage?

What happens in the green-only stage if the green dial is set to 5, and there are 4 green balls left? Does it release just 4 green balls, 4 green and 1 pink, or go straight to the pink-only stage?

Comment: @HughMeyers, I didn't catch that. Thank you for pointing it out. At least one gumball must be released. It is possible for zero (0) gumballs of one color or another to be released but the alternate color cannot go lower than one (1). Let me think about how to add that as a rule and I'll edit the original question.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, The percentage is related to how many pink gumballs are left in the container from where it was initially filled. I'll work to clarify that in the rules. Thank you for the observation. So at 70% starting with 100 P it will release P+G until 70 P is reached

Comment: I modified the instructions to clarify that the percentage is related to the number of pink gumballs at the start of the day. Please let me know if you see any other issues.

Comment: I also added an extra rule to clarify that at least one gumball must be released per turn until the machine is empty.

Comment: and how come the arrangement of gumballs is identical front and back?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, are you talking about the diagram? Because I copied the front image to use as a starting point to make the back.  

Comment: I'm very confused by questions 3 and 4 still... Surely releasing only one ball at a time (eg percentage 100, green and pink dials at 1 each) will net maximum money? And likewise to get minimum money you just set the percentage to zero and all other dials to max and it will output the balls at the maximum rate and thus make you the least money. How does their relative value factor into this at all?

Comment: @Chris, I'm reluctant to answer your inquiry until everyone agrees on what the correct answers are for all four questions. But I will say this, I once took a very difficult certification test that included questions like this for a specific purpose.

Comment: @RogueVeggie: I'm a bit confused. Either my analysis is correct and the answer is trivial and the information on relative values is pointless or there is something in the question I am not understanding and it needs clarification.

Comment: One possible point of my confusion is that question one talks about spending money to get the gumballs but questions 3 and 4 are talking about getting money. Are we actually changing perspective here? Question 1 is about the customer spending money and having no control over the settings. I assumed question three was from the point of view of the machine owner setting the settings to make maximum money from the machine. He already owns the gumballs so he isn't buying them so the value isn't relevant there.

Comment: I don't see how the values are relevant to the consumer without more information. We *could* be considering the value to the person using the machine to get gumballs but they are not getting any money so that doesn't make sense either... For the question to be non-trivial I *must* be not understanding what you mean about the relative values of the gumballs or something about how you get money in the last two questions...

Comment: Q1 is about how much customers will spend to get the gumballs using the example. Q3 & Q4 are about how much or little money the owner of the machine can expect to make depending on the settings. Q2 is an algorithm the owner can use to determine what will happen for every possible setting.

Comment: @Chris That also confused me. I discussed the trivial solution in my answer, based on how I'd most naturally interpret the wording of the question, but focused on what I presume to be the actual intended interpretation (since it results in a non-trivial question): "two green gumballs equals one pink gumball" does not refer to the cost to you when you come to restock the machine, but to the dial for the green-only phase being set to twice the value of the dial for the pink-only phase, and possibly also the green dial for the pink-and-green phase being set to twice the value of the pink (cont)

Comment: (cont) dial for the pink-and-green phase: i.e. it refers to the cost to the customer. (This interpretation has not been confirmed, or for that matter denied, by @RogueVeggie, however.)

Comment: So let's say on the day we buy the machine and 500 pink and 500 green gumballs: The pink gumballs are 1 penny each and are solid gum all the way through. The green gumballs are 2 for 1 penny because they are only 50% gum and the center is hollow. --  let's stick with that for the puzzle for now. --- What happens after all gumballs are used and we go to the gumball maker and now the price has changed per gumball type because of a change in quantity of gum in one or both, cost of manufacturing, or cost for dye colors? Whatever the reason there is a change in price per gumball. Does this help?

Comment: Ok, so it turns out my interpretation was wrong and Chris's was correct. In that case, I agree with them that the price of the gumballs has no bearing on the dial-setting strategy. It does not matter which gumballs are sold from the machine to the customer for which price: you are assuming the machine is eventually emptied, so all that matters is how the number of turns that took relates to the price you paid for the gumballs you filled it with, and the number of turns it takes the customer to empty the machine is independent of the cost of the gumballs to you. The only thing you can (cont)

Comment: (cont) change about your strategy to affect your profits is the number of pink and green balls you fill it with at the start, and obviously the optimal and pessimal strategies are trivial (as I said in my answer): the optimal strategy is to fill it entirely with whichever colour is cheaper, and the pessimal to fill it with whichever is more expensive. (The number of turns it takes the customer to empty the machine is independent of the cost of the gumballs to you, because however much each colour costs you always want to maximise the number of turns it takes to empty the machine.)

Comment: what happens if you set some of the sliders to zero? not very happy punters I imagine!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, yeah that's why we now have: •At least one gumball of either color must be released for each penny until the machine is empty. This means if P=0 then G>=1 else if G=0 then P>=1

Comment: At the moment I'm leaning towards @Neremanth having the best answer. Simple truth is my job has prevented me from taking the time to verify what he has.

Comment: "She" :) (For future reference - obviously you weren't to know!) Glad you liked my answer, whether you end up accepting it or not; of course I understand you'll need to take the time to work it through, and that that might take a while as it's quite verbose! Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Neremanth, after removing my foot from mouth, apologies. One day I'll find a way to stick with non-gender terms. First, I must convince my monkey brain that it needs to be more ejukated (sp?). ;-)

Comment: @RogueVeggie No worries! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I've only spoilered the answer to the first question because the answers to the others were a bit too lengthy.)

1)

(I initially understood the percentage as referring to what percentage of all gumballs left in the machine are pink, but the OP's comment below the question indicates that it actually refers to the percentage of the original number of pink gumballs that are currently left, so I'm going with that interpretation.)

> The machine begins by dispensing 1 pink and 1 green gumball for each penny, and continues to do this until there are 70% of the original number of pink gumballs left. 70% of 140 is 98, so this phase continues for 140 - 98 = 42 rounds, and so costs 42 pennies.

Then,

> the machine then enters its next phase, wherein it dispenses 2 green gumballs for each penny, and continues to do this until there are no green gumballs left. The first round dispensed one green gumball per round for 42 rounds, so at the start of the second phase there are 100 - 42 = 58 green gumballs left. The second phase thus lasts for 58/2 = 29 rounds, and so costs 29 pennies.

Finally,

> the machine enters its third phase, wherein it dispenses 1 pink gumball for each penny, and continues to do this until there are no pink gumballs left. After the first round, there were 98 pink gumballs left, and this remained unchanged during the second round, which dispensed no pink gumballs, so the third phase will last for 98 rounds, and so cost 98 pennies.

So,

> Putting all the phases together, we have 42 + 29 + 98 pennies to release all the gumballs, which is 169 pennies.

**2)**

Let $N_p$ be the initial number of pink gumballs, $N_g$ be the initial number of green gumballs, $P$ be the percentage setting, $D_{p1}$ be the number of pink dispensed per penny in the pink-and-green phase, $D_{g1}$ be the number of green dispensed per penny in the pink-and-green phase, $D_{p2}$ be the number of pink dispensed per penny in the pink-only phase, and $D_{g2}$ be the number of green dispensed per penny in the green-only phase.

If $N_p$ is 0, presumably the machine will skip the pink-and-green phase, go straight into the green-only phase, continue till all green gumballs are dispensed, and then skip the pink-only phase as well. In this case, the number of rounds (and thus pennies), which we will denote by $R_2$, will either be the largest whole number such that $D_{g2}$ multiplied by that number is less than $N_g$ (sorry, I'm pretty sure there's a name for that, but my maths was a long time ago and I've forgotten it! Let's call it $L$.), or $L+1$. If $N_g$ is a multiple of $D_{g2}$, it will be $L$, and if not then it will be $L+1$.

If $N_g$ is 0, then (if $D_{g1}>0$) it is not entirely clear from the rules what happens: does the machine skip straight to the pink-only phase, or does it dispense the appropriate number of pink gumballs each turn for the pink-and-green phase, even though it cannot accompany them with the appropriate number of green gumballs, until the percentage of pink gumballs is reached? Assuming the former, the number of rounds and thus pennies (which we will denote by $R_3$) can be calculated in the same way as for the case where $N_p$ was 0, replacing all the $g$s with $p$s.

If $N_g$ and $N_p$ are both non-zero, then the machine starts in the pink-and-green phase. It is known that this will terminate when the number of pink gumballs remaining drops below $P$% of $N_p$. As already mentioned, it is not clear from the rules whether it also terminates when the number of green gumballs reaches 0, but we will assume that it does.

This issue does not arise in any case when $N_g/D_{g1}$ is greater than $100-P$% of $N_p$ divided by $D_{p1}$. In this case, the pink-and-green phase continues for $R_1$ rounds, where $R_1$ is the smallest number such that $R_1\times D_{p1}>(1-P/100)\times N_p$. At the end of the first phase, there are $N_p - (R_1 \times D_{p1})$ pink and $N_g - (R_1 \times D_{g1})$ green gumballs left.

If $N_g/D_{g1}$ is less than or equal to $100-P$% of $N_p$ divided by $D_{p1}$, then the number of rounds in the pink-and-green phase, which we will again denote $R_1$, is $N_g/D_{g1}$ if that is a whole number, and otherwise it is 1 + the largest number which when multiplied by $D_{g1}$ gives a value less than $N_g$.

If there are any green gumballs left after the first phase (i.e. if $N_g/D_{g1}$ is greater than $100-P$% of $N_p$ divided by $D_{p1}$), then the machine enters the green-only phase for a number of rounds which we will denote by $R_2$. If there are no green gumballs left after the first phase (i.e. if $N_g/D_{g1}$ is less than or equal to $100-P$% of $N_p$ divided by $D_{p1}$) then $R_2=0$.

If the machine does enter the green-only phase, then it will do so with $N_g - (R_1 \times D_{g1})$ green gumballs. For simplicity, let us refer to this number as $N_{g2}$. If $N_{g2}/D_{g2}$ is a whole number, then $R_2=N_{g2}/D_{g2}$. Otherwise, $R_2$ is 1 greater than the largest number such that $D_{g2}$ multiplied by that number is less than $N_{g2}$.

Finally, the machine will enter the pink-only phase, for $R_3$ rounds, provided that $N_p - (R_1 \times D_{p1}) > 0$ (if that is not the case then $R_3$ will be 0), and there will be $N_p - (R_1 \times D_{p1})$ pink gumballs at the start of this round. Let us call this number $N_{p2}$ for simplicity. $R_3$ can now be calculated in the same way as $R_2$ was, replacing $g$ by $p$ throughout.

The total number of pennies is then given by $R_1+R_2+R_3$.

**3) and 4)**

The price that you pay for the gumballs has no bearing on the dial-setting strategy. This is because throughout we have been assuming that the customer (or a steady stream of different customers) will keep inserting pennies regardless of how attractive to them the offer of a certain number of gumballs of a certain colour or colours is. Unlike in the real world, the fact that pink gumballs cost you twice as much as green gumballs do has no implications for how you should price them in the machine, because you don't have to worry that the customers won't go for inferior green gumballs offered at the same price as the pink ones, and you can just go ahead and set the $D_{p2}$ and $D_{g2}$ both to 1, and $P$ to 100, so that the machine enters the green-only phase right from the beginning, followed by the pink-only phase, and only ever dispenses one gumball for a penny; it does not matter what you set $D_{p1}$ and $D_{g1}$ to since these dials will never come into play. (This must be the strategy that maximises your revenue, since each turn must dispense at least one gumball, so there is no room for improvement.)

Similarly, for the least revenue, you need to maximise the number of gumballs released every turn, and if (as shown in the illustration) the dials governing the number of gumballs released all have the same maximum, then the way to ensure the most gumballs are released per turn is to have the machine stay in the pink-and-green phase throughout, so that you get the maximum number of each of two colours instead of the maximum number of just one, and so you must set $P$ to 0 and $D_{p1}$ and $D_{g1}$ both to their maximum possible values. (It does not matter what you set $D_{g2}$ and $D_{p2}$ to.)

The only thing you can change about your strategy which is determined by the cost to you of the gumballs is the number of pink and green balls you fill it with at the start, and the optimal and pessimal strategies are trivial: the optimal strategy is to fill it entirely with whichever colour is cheaper, and the pessimal to fill it with whichever is more expensive.

To summarise, your profit is how much more money you get from people inserting pennies into the machine than you spent in stocking it. You maximise profit by a) maximising the revenue from the machine, which means maximising the number of turns it takes to empty it, which is unrelated to how much each gumball costs you when stocking it, and b) minimising the amount you spend on stocking the machine, which does depend on the relative cost to you of the different colours of gumball.

Comment: I just started reading your fantastically detailed answer and I'm stuck on the "state in which there are still gumballs inside it, but no further turns will dispense any gumballs." I just updated the rules to clarify a few things and one is that at least one gumball must be released per turn until the machine is empty. How does this change your answer, or am I just missing something? I'll continue reading to see!

I appreciate everyone's effort in this puzzle!

Comment: Yes, that was because at the time I wrote the answer, the rules weren't clear as to what would happen in the case where the machine was supposed to dispense some number of gumballs of a particular colour on the next turn, but there were fewer than that number remaining in it. For example, in the pink-only state, if it was supposed to dispense 7 per penny but there were only 6 left: would it dispense those 6 on the next turn, or go into a sulk and refuse to dispense anything further since it couldn't dispense the whole 7. (The rules explained that if a single gumball was left, it would (cont)

Comment: (cont) be dispensed on the next turn, but didn't deal with the case where more than one remained.) You've now clarified that at least one gumball must be dispensed per turn till the machine is empty, which rules out the possibility of it reaching a state where it refuses to dispense anything before it's actually empty, but I think it's still not quite clear exactly what does happen: supposing it is in the pink-only state, with 6 pink gumballs left, and it's supposed to dispense 7 per penny, will it dispense all 6 on the next turn, dispense the remaining balls one by one over the next 6 (cont)

Comment: (cont) turns, or something else? (The first option seems most logical, but is not actually specified.) What about if it's in the pink-and-green state, with only 3 green gumballs left but it's supposed to dispense 4 (and some number of pink) on the next turn? Does it dispense the correct number of pink and all the remaining green, then move to the pink-only state? Or move straight to the green-only state? Does it make a difference whether that turn would have brought the pink gumballs under the percentage threshold?

Comment: As to how it affects my answer, it basically means that certain contingencies I'd considered are not actually possible and can be ruled out. I'll edit my answer accordingly (but will probably wait till the weekend when I have more time, and when you might have clarified the rules further to deal with the ambiguity I just identified).

Comment: I see the issue I've created here... If there is any remainder of a setting, such as 6 when set to 7, it will dispense 6 remainder. Likewise if we are in the P+G phase and there is a remainder of Pink to reach the <=% it will dispense the remainder of Pink to reach the % or lower. I'll clarify that as soon as I have access to a computer. My cell phone  thumb typing skills are lower than the set %. 

Comment: OK, I modified the rules and added clarification about remainders just above the four questions.

Comment: I really like how you show your work in detail.

Comment: @RogueVeggie Thanks! I'm not seeing where you added the clarification about remainders, but I think that might be because I'm on my phone and it doesn't always refresh properly. Anyway, I understand that aspect of its behaviour now thanks to your comment, and will edit my answer tomorrow. (It's not wrong currently, as far as I'm aware; it just has some stuff about other possible interpretations of the rules that can be removed now you've clarified what the behaviour is.)

Comment: @RogueVeggie Ok, I see your edit to the question now. That clarifies the behaviour when it reaches a state where only gumballs of one colour are left, and there are fewer of them than it is supposed to dispense in the phase where it dispenses only this colour, but leaves its behaviour in certain other situations still undefined. May I suggest, based on my understanding of your comment, this wording instead? "If the machine reaches a point where there are too few gumballs of one or both colours for it to be able to dispense the correct numbers of gumballs for the phase it is currently in (cont)

Comment: (cont) but there are still some gumballs remaining of at least one of the colours it is supposed to dispense in this phase, then it dispenses all the remaining gumballs of the colour(s) for which it can't dispense the correct number (and, if applicable, the correct number of the other). It then moves to the next phase on the next turn."

Comment: Let me see if I can shorten or paraphrase what you just typed. otherwise I will likely copy what you have here.

Comment: @RogueVeggie Have just edited my answer to remove the bits you've now clarified to be unnecessary, and to change my answer to 3 and 4 now that I understand what you were asking.

Comment: Without a doubt the most detailed answer. I had to have a coworker review it to make sure it all made sense and was correct.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a SQL function to answer part 2 of the question. Try it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00a6e/1/0).

Essentially, it takes as input the number of pink gumballs in the machine, the number of green gumballs in the machine, the percent (as a decimal), the number set on the first phase pink dial, the number set on the first phase green dial, the number set on the second phase green dial, and the number set on the third phase pink dial.

It's obviously not gonna find the answer to 3 and 4, but it's an accurate answer to 2.

NB: To run the function, simply replace the numbers in the field on the right with the appropriate values, then press "Run SQL."

Edit: CODE

```
create function Gumballs(@Pink int, @Green int,
                         @pct numeric(3,2), 
                         @PinkPGPhase int, @GreenPGPhase int,
                         @PinkDialPhase int, @GreenDialPhase int)
                         returns int as 
                         begin

                         declare @result int = 0
                         declare @PinkStart int = @Pink

                         While @Pink >= @pct*(@PinkStart)
                         BEGIN
                         set @result+=1 
                         set @Pink-=@PinkPGPhase
                         set @Green-=@GreenPGPhase
                         END

                         WHILE @Green > 0 
                         BEGIN
                         set @Green-=@GreenDialPhase
                         set @result+=1
                         END

                         WHILE @Pink > 0 
                         BEGIN
                         set @Pink-=@PinkDialPhase
                         set @result+=1
                         END 

                         RETURN @result

                         end
```

To run it, here's the query:

```
SELECT dbo.Gumballs(140, --pink gumballs
                    100, --green gumballs
                    .7,  --percentage
                    1,   --pink/green shared phase--pink dial
                    1,   --pink/green shared phase--green dial
                    1,   --pink alone phase dial
                    2)   --green alone phase dial
```

This returns 169.

Comment: Can you put the code and results in your answer? (The link might break at some time)

Comment: Suuuuuuuuuuure.

Comment: This certainly works as a solution for the second question (and the first) under the interpretation of the rules that I originally had, but it's now been clarified that that interpretation is incorrect: the pink-and-green phase stops not when the number of pink balls remaining falls below a certain percentage of the total remaining balls, but when the number of pink balls remaining falls below a certain percentage of the original number of pink balls.

Comment: Thanks @Neremanth! I've updated my answer to take that into account.

Comment: you need >= otherwise phase 1 never happens.

Comment: Apologies for not making all these things clear from the beginning. In fact I just had to modify a little more to clarify what happens with remainders. Thank you all for pointing out the flaws so I can correct them.

Comment: @phroureo, when I try testing your script on SQL Fiddle I constantly get 190 no matter how I modify the input numbers. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: @RogueVeggie it looks like the SQL fiddle wasn't updated with the new code when it was changed. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. My first test so far is to set the % to zero (0) and it shows 141 pennies. I don't think that's possible. Setting % to .01 returns 140.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 is straight-forward:

> 30% of 140 is 42 in PG phase, then 58/2=29 in G phase, and then  140-42=98 in P phase. Total 140+29=**169**.

A JavaScript calculator for question 2:

[JSFiddle gumball calculator](https://jsfiddle.net/JonMarkPerry/y2rj4316/)

```
<input type='number' id='pinit' value='140'/><label for='pinit'>Pink start</label><br>
<input type='number' id='ginit' value='100'/><label for='ginit'>Green start</label><br>
<input type='number' id='per' value='70'/><label for='per'>Percentage</label><br>
<input type='number' id='pgp' value='1'/><label for='pgp'>Pink+Green Pink</label><br>
<input type='number' id='pgg' value='1'/><label for='pgg'>Pink+Green Green</label><br>
<input type='number' id='g' value='2'/><label for='g'>Green</label><br>
<input type='number' id='p' value='1'/><label for='p'>Pink</label><br>

<button onclick='calculate();'>Calculate</button>
<br>
<span id='outpg'></span> in pink and green phase<br>
<span id='outg'></span> in green phase<br>
<span id='outp'></span> in pink phase<br>
Total : <span id='output'></span>

<script>

function calculate() {
var res=0;
var pLeft=pinit.value;
var gLeft=ginit.value;

nPG=Math.ceil(pinit.value*(100-per.value)/(pgp.value*100));
pLeft-=nPG*pgp.value;
gLeft-=nPG*pgg.value;
res=nPG;
outpg.textContent=nPG;
chgG=Math.ceil(gLeft/g.value);
res+=chgG;
outg.textContent=chgG;
chgP=Math.ceil(pLeft/p.value);
res+=chgP;
outp.textContent=chgP;
output.textContent=res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: My calculations go like this: start with 140 pink and 100 green. You get one pink and one green for 70 rounds at which point you have 70 pink and 30 green. This is the 70% mark when the distribution changes. Now you get 2 green until all the green are gone: 30/2 = 15. Lastly, you get 1 pink per turn: 70. Total: 70+15+70=155.

Comment: For 1 it's the example settings, right? There's no optimization. You either get the answer right or wrong. I'm not sure how you interpreted the example.

Comment: OP doesn't say what the 70% is of - i went for initial number of pinks

Comment: in yours, after you release 1 green gumball, the percentage is above 70% again, so what happens? do we go back to PG phase? which sounds very silly to me.@HughMeyers

Comment: All, thank you very much for identifying issues, I greatly appreciate it. I'll work to clarify the original question during my lunch break. Lets say the machine is filled with 100 P gumballs at the beginning of the day and the percentage is set to 70. the machine will release P+G until there are only 70 P available. At this point it will go to the next step of only releasing G.

Comment: I modified the instructions to clarify that the percentage is related to the number of pink gumballs at the start of the day. Please let me know if you see any other issues.

Comment: I've added clarification about remainders in the original question. There was some confusion with that part. Let me know if you see any other issues and I'll do my best to fix.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry testing out your JavaScript I see we get negative (-) numbers of green gumballs once we drop to 27% or lower.

Comment: Looking at your script makes me want to see it work! Definitely like where you're going with #2